Why does the RF Bypass capacitor have to have larger capacitance than DC Block ones?
I'm analyzing the following circuit.

The S-parameters are listed below.

However, when I change the capacitance of C1 back to value all the other capacitors have (12 pF), the S-parameters look like this.

Why is that? Also, why does the value of the capacitance of C5 not contribute to any changes in the S-parameters? No value I used had an effect. Could it be because the RF choke inductors already suppress the AC signal?

Put another way from @Justme:
If you were well below the transistor's \$F_T\$, then the emitter's effective resistance would be about \$1\Omega\$ (because, \$26 \mathrm{mV} / 28 \mathrm{mA}\$).  Things are going to be different at \$1.8 \mathrm{GHz}\$, but the emitter's effective impedance to ground is still going to be considerably lower than the \$50\Omega\$ seen by C3 and C4.
You want your DC blocking caps to have a reactance of at least \$\frac 1 4\$ of the working impedance of your circuit -- so those \$12 \mathrm{pF}\$ caps  in their \$50\Omega\$ signal paths make sense.  Put a cap into a signal path with a \$1\Omega\$-ish impedance, and it needs to be way lower.
Hence, \$150\mathrm{pF}\$.

Great response. Thank you. I'm not familiar with FT though. What do you mean?

Do they not teach this in RF circuit classes anymore?  $F_T$ is the frequency at which the current gain of a transistor drops to 1.  Also called "transition frequency".  There's material out there in the web, and in just about any introductory text on transistor circuit design.

$f_T$ is not provided for Q1 by Avago as parasitic ESL effects the results above 1GHz for this package.  You can reverse engineer the reactance from the s parms but these are more relevant. (-1)

The bypass cap needs to be as large as necessary to keep the voltage swing of the emitter as small as necessary with the current changes emitted from the emitter. As the difference between 12pF and 150pF is more than a decade, it also means larger cap is more than a decade better keeping the voltage stable. From another point of view, at 1.8 GHz, the 12pF is an impedance of about 7 ohms and 150pF is about 0.6 ohms, so there is about 10x difference on the voltage swing based on the current swing.
The C5 is irrelevant if the voltage supply is ideal. If the supply is ideal, there will always be 12V over C5 and no current in or out of C5 at any frequency.

What does parasitic L in the emitter path do to your answer?

@D.A.S. And this parasitic L in the emitter path is drawn where exactly? I think there is none modeled externally. Only internal to the transistor.

Exactly where you indicated, with ideal passives + traces making it worse.

Every conductor has some effective series inductance (ESL) and resistance, R, ESR or Rs.
Where this matters most is on power rails and bypass caps when you want to null AC impedance. But the only time you can null reactance is a series LC circuit at resonance.
ESL rises with the log of the length/width ratio with some constant, k that varies for flat traces,  round wires or square cap terminals being the best if the length is less than the width.
ESL has a nominal value of 0.5 nH/mm for short paths and maybe 1nH/mm for long paths with the same width, but it can be more or less.

Let's say your emitter bypass cap and traces are ESL = 1 nH max.

Then for 1.8GHz your optimal gain C value will be closer to 8 pF.

Your BW should be around 400 MHz into 50 Ohms but your emitter driver
impedance depends on the \$r_\pi\$ your current and transistor capacitance Cbe and \$\beta\$.

You could add a few to the emitter to trade off a bit of gain for BW,
but that will also add some ESL.

The hybrid-\$\pi\$ model is as follows;
\$g_m = \frac{ Ic }{ V_{t} } , r_\pi = \frac{\beta}{g_m} \$,


I will let you do the math and verify or ask questions.
If you are interested, there is more to it for the RF version of a classic old transistor.
https://2n3904blog.com/common-emitter-output-impedance/
Smaller SMT caps have an advantage for higher f but construction is also important so pay attention to self-resonant frequency, and/or s-parms in the caps you choose.
Conclusion
A lower emitter Cap give more gain (s21) may be due to approaching series resonance from the ESL of the transistor, Cap or traces when you lay it out.
Learn how to estimate layout ESL based on the dimensions of parts and traces.
I like the simple calculators in Saturn's free PCB tools.
1mm has a lot of ESL for UHF
\$X_{L} = 2 \pi fL, ~~~  
 ESL = 2 \pi  *1.8 ~[GHz]*1~[mm]*(est.)0.5~[nH/mm] ~ =~6~\Omega\$
Even if you neglect all the Q1, chip capacitance (est.<=3pF) for now, look only at the lead length of the transistor.
\$Av = \dfrac{Rc}{(X_{ESL}) + r_\pi} \$.
You may reflect on why UHF transistors tend to look like satellites with solar panels.  This is to reduce ESL by lowering the length/width ratio.
The Avago NPN is a nice, low cost, low noise, transistor but it does suffer in your design of a grounded common emitter.   But your choice of design with this model package suffers greatly from ESL.
Adding Re in series will reduce this effect lowering Tau=L/R and other are other improvements.
ESL in the high base impedance you may neglect at 1.8GHz.


Source: https://www.modelithics.com/models/Vendor/Avago/AT-41533.pdf
My estimates and opinions are my own, trust but verify your own.
